# Python minidom: #text node disappears when appending it to new parent node

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<example>
     <para>
         <phrase>child_0</phrase>
         child_1
         <phrase>child_2</phrase>
     </para>
</example>
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
<foo>
    <phrase>child_0</phrase>
    child_1
    <phrase>child_2</phrase>
</foo>
```

Simple, right? I create a new parent node -- `<foo>` -- and then iterate through the `<para>` node and append the children to the new `<foo>` node.

What's strange is that the `child_1` (a text node) disappears when I try to do so. If I simply iterate through the `<para>` node, I get this:

```
>>> for p in para.childNodes:
        print p.nodeType
1
3
1
```

So there are 3 child nodes, and the middle one is the text node. But when I try to append it to the new `<foo>` node, it doesn't make it.

```
>>> for p in para.childNodes:
        foo_node.appendChild(p)

>>> print foo_node.toprettyxml()
<foo>
    <phrase>child_0</phrase>
    <phrase>child_2</phrase>
</foo>
```

What the `@#$%&*!` is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here I am, answering my own question.

The `appendChild()` function **removes** the child node from the `<para>` list of nodes, so you will be effectively skipping every other element as the index gets out of sync with each iteration. The solution is to append a *copy* of the node:

```
for p in para.childNodes:
    p_copy = p.cloneNode(deep=True)
    foo_node.appendChild(p_copy)
```