# Text dissappears after it is added to a paragraph (HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html

So I made a program that takes a value (decimal number) and replaces it with its binary value. The calculating part works perfectly. Then I made a html document that should add the binary value to an empty paragraph when a button is clicked. It adds it to the paragraph but just as it is added, it dissapears. You can see it just for a split second. I got the idea for the JS part from another article ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764061/adding-text-to-an-existing-text-element-in-javascript-via-dom/41764179)). Everyone said it works fine for them. So if anyone can help, I'd be very grateful.

```
function decimalToBinary() {

            var decimalNumber = document.getElementById('decimalNumber').value
            // Holds the value entered in the input box

            // ... some code that calculates the binary value 

            var result = new String(valueOfTheBinaryNumber)      

            var resultParagraph = document.createElement("p");
            var resultText = document.createTextNode(result);
            resultParagraph.appendChild(resultText);
            var element = document.getElementById("main")
            element.appendChild(resultParagraph)
        }
```

```html
  <input type="number" name="Decimal Number" id="decimalNumber" min="0" step="0.0001">
  <button onclick="decimalToBinary()">Convert</button>    
  <p id="p"></p>
```

I edited in a new, simpler way to get the result as a paragraph but still dissappears in a split second.

Comment: what value are you passing as an argument to `decimalToBinary()` at `onclick` event?

Comment: when yuo run decimalToBinary() from your click event, you're not passing in any value for `decimalNumber`

Comment: Might be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859341/python-minidom-text-node-disappears-when-appending-it-to-new-parent-node

Comment: the argument is passed from the input box. I'll add it to the code above

Comment: Look at the semicolons